# Creating small program in python which executes SQL code based on input

Tags: python

I am trying to develop small app to simplify my work. I know to code in R and VBA, but I would really like to start doing the python as it is more and more popular.

My app should execute the SQL code which is following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE column1 LIKE 'user input  in label1'
  AND column2 LIKE 'user input  in label2'
```

User form should look like this on the picture:

[image]

So user (usually me) should enter values in label1 and label2 and by clicking button execute the SQL. Export should be put into the excel file.

Many thanks in advance for help.

Regards

Comment: What is your question? Please show the code you've already implemented and describe which part you are stuck on.

Comment: Hello, here are some modules you can look into to test by yourself.
`csv` for dealing with excel files, `sqlalchemy` or `sqlite3` for the database based on your needs, `dash` for a web interface easily programmable or `tkinter` for a classic gui.

Comment: Hello Juan Carlos.  It is difficult to understand what you are asking.  You could be asking how to draw the form shown in your image; you could be asking how to write code that is executed when the button is clicked; you could be asking how to write code that queries an SQL database; or you could be asking how to write code that will store the results of the SQL query in an Excel file.  Your readers don't want to waste your time (or their own time) telling you how to do things you already know how to do.  Please edit your post to focus on one question - see [ask] and [mcve] for more guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have a specific code question but are looking for getting started information, I'm going to point you to a few places to find what you need.

There are a few packages that can query a database. My favorite is [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc).

If you want a gui, [tkinter](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm) is a good place to start.

Here's some basic code for querying. tkinter can be a little involved, so you should really read up on that to understand it.

```
label1 = 'foo' # You can replace these with variables gathered by tkinter
label2 = 'bar'

from pyodbc import connect
import pandas

conn_string = 'DSN=my_database' # Use your own connection string here

conn = connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 LIKE ? AND column2 LIKE ?",
               ['%' + label1 + '%', '%' + label2 + '%'])

results = cursor.fetchall()
cols = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
results = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(results, columns=cols)

cursor.close()
del cursor
conn.close()
```

**UPDATE:**

As roganjosh points out in the comments, you shouldn't use fstrings because this leaves you vulnerable to sql injection. There's a good discussion about it in the comments if you're interested.

Comment: You should not be using `f` strings to create SQL queries, particularly where user input is involved. It's a serious SQL injection risk.

Comment: Even with a few fellow employees DON'T USE f-STRINGS TO BUILD YOUR QUERIES! You should never *ever* build your own queries - it's not even easier, and what happens the first time you accidentally put the wrong value in there? It's terrible advice. Just don't do it.

Comment: Than you both for your input. Please help me develop some better practices. Let's assume you only have read rights to the database and you only use it internally, what's wrong with that? Also, what's an alternative?

Comment: The alternative is to do it _properly_ with a parameterized query: `cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 LIKE ? AND column2 LIKE ?""", ['%' + table1 + '%', '%' + table2 + '%'])`

Comment: @roganjosh missing one `)`; I'd prefer using `[ ]` for the parameters because they're less likely to be misused with `%`

Comment: I forgot to put '%' at the beginning and end of the columns, but I'm not seeing a difference here. Couldn't you define table1 and table2 as something malicious?

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD 327 Link](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @MichaelCox no, because as the arguments are unpacked into the the `?` placeholders, they're automatically escaped to prevent any arbitrary SQL command from being executed. This does not happen with string formatting. Note that I am supplying the values as a second argument to the `execute()` method.

Comment: Ok. So, it's not some default Python feature? It's part of the execute() method?

Comment: Exactly :) And some SQL libraries use `%s` as the placeholder, not `?` which just adds to the confusion; it's not the same as the string formatting `%s`. This issue is rife on Stack Overflow and if you think we might have overstressed things, have a look at this [pie chart](https://blog.alertlogic.com/blog/tried-and-true-sql-injection-still-a-leading-method-of-cyber-attack/)

Comment: Note that you cannot parameterize table names or column names, only parameters. If they need to be variable then you _do_ need to use string formatting and you need to ensure that they are safe. This is easier to do because you can cross-reference any input against the database schema

Comment: An easy way to check table/column names is something like `table_names = {'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'bar'}; table_name = table_names[user_input]`. There are probably better ways to do it, but then you'll only get a KeyError when they try to select from little bobby tables.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. This has been very educational. I updated my answer to remove the f-strings.

Answer (score 0):

for graphical UI, you can use the python module `tkinter` (read [documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) here) - for database queries, there are a few modules available, e.g. `sqlite3`. Try them out and come back with specific questions.